# Facebook Fan Page access token retrieval

Tags: php

I want to retrieve the fan page access token via the following php codes but no success. Any idea?

```
     $account_url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$page_id."/accounts?"
    . "&method=GET"
    . "&access_token=xxxx";

    $accounts = json_decode( file_get_contents($account_url) );

    $data = $accounts['data'];
    foreach($data as $account) {
        if( $account['id'] == $fanpage_id )
            $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using graph API :

events.php :

```
<?php

$facebook_appid         = "your appid";                                 // Facebook appplication id
$facebook_secret        = "your secret";                // Facebook secret id
$facebook_pageid        = "your pageid";                                // Facebook secret id
$redirect_uri           = "https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
//$redirect_uri         = "https://localhost/facebook_page/fb_login.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
$scope                  = "user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_stream,user_events,friends_events"; // User permission for facebook


$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"]?$_REQUEST["code"]:"";

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state']  = rand(); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url         = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&state=". $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$scope;
    header("location:".$dialog_url);
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] == $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url          = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri). "&client_secret=" . $facebook_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response           = @file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params             = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $account_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_pageid."?fields=access_token&access_token=".$params['access_token'];
    $resp               = @file_get_contents($account_url);

    $dt                 =   json_decode($resp);


    echo "Page accesstoken :".$dt->access_token;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Page id : ".$dt->id;  

}

?>
```

Please note : `$redirect_uri = https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php` should be same as website url in facebook application page settings.